# Lens optic jumping between 17-24 on Sigma 17-70 f/2.8-4 DC Macro OS HSM

Tags: lens, sigma, used-equipment

I've bought a used lens and I would I am unsure if I should return it.

An inner element visibly jumps between the 17-24 mark. It does not interfere with function or focusing. However, is this an early sign of damage that I should avoid?

Notes:

- Switched On: present
- Switched Off: absent
- OS On: Present
- OS Off: Present
- AF: Present
- MF: Present

I've returned the lens because I don't believe that OS should results in a movement so distinct, so I'm inclined to believe this is loose element.

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdjPqfgDuug

Comment: This question is almost certainly one you should ask the manufacturer.  Only they can be definitive about the correct behavior.

Comment: Can you describe "visibly jumps" in more detail? Do you mean that it seems _loose_ when the zoom is in that range, or that as you are zooming, you can see an element move quickly instead of smoothly? Is the zoom itself smooth?

Comment: Here is a video. I have intiated a refund. But this can be useful to other members: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdjPqfgDuug

Comment: It'd be really cool if you got in touch with Sigma, showed them the video, and then posted the response as an answer to this so that anyone else having the issue doesn't have to go through the whole process again. (It seems someone on your youtube is already suffering the same)

Comment: I already did. They only recommended that I send it to them. But I returned that lens and I suspect the unfortunate commentor was probably the next victim. The seller deleted my negative review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the ball bearing has come out of position on the optical stabaliser (sounds similar to an issue I had).

To get to it you need to strip down the lens to its bones to re-seat.

Tried to do it myself but broke a ribbon cable inside and…well it's stuffed, but the image doesn't jump any more.